# Getting following errors while running my spring boot application which include dependencies of JPA,spring web, spring security, Sql and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets, web-container

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_241]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:437) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at com.example.demo.MoneyMakerAppApplication.main(MoneyMakerAppApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5056) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1321) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
... 40 common frames omitted

2020-08-03 10:42:41.369 ERROR 7792 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:437) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at com.example.demo.MoneyMakerAppApplication.main(MoneyMakerAppApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5056) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1321) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
... 40 common frames omitted

2020-08-03 10:42:41.370  INFO 7792 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-08-03 10:42:41.397  WARN 7792 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2020-08-03 10:42:41.407  INFO 7792 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-03 10:42:41.415 ERROR 7792 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1321)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

The method's class, javax.servlet.ServletContext, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/Rohit%20Roy/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.37/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
```

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext: file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.servlet.ServletContext

Comment: The error already tells you what to fix. **Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of` javax.servlet.ServletContext`**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion M. Deinum but I don't know how to correct classpath in eclipse IDE or STS.

Comment: The classpath is derived from what you defined in your `pom.xml` as dependencies.